# Unable Login To Sfdc Org Using Bulk Api Java Code

Tags: bulk-api

I am using Bulk Api for data migration from oracle db to Sfdc Org through Java Code. For logging into the Salesforce org i am using the Soap Api by generating the partner jar. I am getting the following error

> Exception in thread "main" com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: unable to find end tag at:  START_TAG seen ...`</orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode><orgDefaultCurrencyLocale>`... @1:930
>       at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.consumeEndTag(TypeMapper.java:437)
>       at com.sforce.soap.partner.GetUserInfoResult.load(GetUserInfoResult.java:1)
>       at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:674)
>       at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:556)
>       at com.sforce.soap.partner.LoginResult.loadFields(LoginResult.java:1)
>       at com.sforce.soap.partner.LoginResult.load(LoginResult.java:1)
>       at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:674)
>       at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:556)
>       at com.sforce.soap.partner.LoginResponse_element.loadFields(LoginResponse_element.java:1)
>       at com.sforce.soap.partner.LoginResponse_element.load(LoginResponse_element.java:1)
>       at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:674)
>       at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:556)
>       at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.bind(SoapConnection.java:180)
>       at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.receive(SoapConnection.java:154)
>       at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:99)
>       at com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection.login(PartnerConnection.java:1)
>       at com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection.(PartnerConnection.java:1)
>       at com.rajendra.connection.BulkExample.getBulkConnection(BulkExample.java:140)
>       at com.rajendra.connection.BulkExample.runSample(BulkExample.java:24)
>       at com.rajendra.connection.BulkExample.main(BulkExample.java:15)

When I googled this issue, most of the answers were related to invalid credentials, but I double checked and those I provide are correct.

```
package com.rajendra.connection;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.sforce.async.*;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig;

public class BulkExample {
public static void main(String[] args)
throws AsyncApiException, ConnectionException, IOException {
BulkExample example = new BulkExample();
// Replace arguments below with your credentials and test file name
// The first parameter indicates that we are loading Account records
example.runSample("Account", "username", "password+securitytoken", "mySampleData.csv");
}

/**
* Creates a Bulk API job and uploads batches for a CSV file.
*/
public void runSample(String sobjectType, String userName,
String password, String sampleFileName)
throws AsyncApiException, ConnectionException, IOException {
BulkConnection connection = getBulkConnection(userName, password);
JobInfo job = createJob(sobjectType, connection);
List<BatchInfo> batchInfoList = createBatchesFromCSVFile(connection, job,
sampleFileName);
closeJob(connection, job.getId());
awaitCompletion(connection, job, batchInfoList);
checkResults(connection, job, batchInfoList);
}

/**
* Gets the results of the operation and checks for errors.
*/
private void checkResults(BulkConnection connection, JobInfo job,
List<BatchInfo> batchInfoList)
throws AsyncApiException, IOException {
// batchInfoList was populated when batches were created and submitted
for (BatchInfo b : batchInfoList) {
CSVReader rdr =
new CSVReader(connection.getBatchResultStream(job.getId(), b.getId()));
List<String> resultHeader = rdr.nextRecord();
int resultCols = resultHeader.size();
List<String> row;
while ((row = rdr.nextRecord()) != null) {
Map<String, String> resultInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < resultCols; i++) {
resultInfo.put(resultHeader.get(i), row.get(i));
}
boolean success = Boolean.valueOf(resultInfo.get("Success"));
boolean created = Boolean.valueOf(resultInfo.get("Created"));

String id = resultInfo.get("Id");
String error = resultInfo.get("Error");
if (success && created) {
System.out.println("Created row with id " + id);
} else if (!success) {
System.out.println("Failed with error: " + error);
}
}
}
}
private void closeJob(BulkConnection connection, String jobId)
throws AsyncApiException {
JobInfo job = new JobInfo();
job.setId(jobId);
job.setState(JobStateEnum.Closed);
connection.updateJob(job);
}
/**
* Wait for a job to complete by polling the Bulk API.
*
* @param connection
* BulkConnection used to check results.
* @param job
* The job awaiting completion.
* @param batchInfoList
* List of batches for this job.
* @throws AsyncApiException
*/
private void awaitCompletion(BulkConnection connection, JobInfo job,
List<BatchInfo> batchInfoList)
throws AsyncApiException {
long sleepTime = 0L;
Set<String> incomplete = new HashSet<String>();
for (BatchInfo bi : batchInfoList) {
incomplete.add(bi.getId());
}
while (!incomplete.isEmpty()) {
try {
Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
System.out.println("Awaiting results..." + incomplete.size());
sleepTime = 10000L;
BatchInfo[] statusList =
connection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo();
for (BatchInfo b : statusList) {
if (b.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Completed
|| b.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Failed) {
if (incomplete.remove(b.getId())) {

System.out.println("BATCH STATUS:\n" + b);
}
}
}
}
}
/**
* Create a new job using the Bulk API.
*
* @param sobjectType
* The object type being loaded, such as "Account"
* @param connection
* BulkConnection used to create the new job.
* @return The JobInfo for the new job.
* @throws AsyncApiException
*/
private JobInfo createJob(String sobjectType, BulkConnection connection)
throws AsyncApiException {
JobInfo job = new JobInfo();
job.setObject(sobjectType);
job.setOperation(OperationEnum.insert);
job.setContentType(ContentType.CSV);
job = connection.createJob(job);
System.out.println(job);
return job;
}
/**
* Create the BulkConnection used to call Bulk API operations.
*/
private BulkConnection getBulkConnection(String userName, String password)
throws ConnectionException, AsyncApiException {
ConnectorConfig partnerConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
partnerConfig.setUsername(userName);
partnerConfig.setPassword(password);
partnerConfig.setAuthEndpoint("https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/38.0");
// Creating the connection automatically handles login and stores
// the session in partnerConfig
new PartnerConnection(partnerConfig);
// When PartnerConnection is instantiated, a login is implicitly
// executed and, if successful,
// a valid session is stored in the ConnectorConfig instance.
// Use this key to initialize a BulkConnection:
ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
config.setSessionId(partnerConfig.getSessionId());
// The endpoint for the Bulk API service is the same as for the normal
// SOAP uri until the /Soap/ part. From here it's '/async/versionNumber'
String soapEndpoint = partnerConfig.getServiceEndpoint();

String apiVersion = "38.0";
String restEndpoint = soapEndpoint.substring(0, soapEndpoint.indexOf("Soap/"))
+ "async/" + apiVersion;
config.setRestEndpoint(restEndpoint);
// This should only be false when doing debugging.
config.setCompression(true);
// Set this to true to see HTTP requests and responses on stdout
config.setTraceMessage(false);
BulkConnection connection = new BulkConnection(config);
return connection;
}
/**
* Create and upload batches using a CSV file.
* The file into the appropriate size batch files.
*
* @param connection
* Connection to use for creating batches
* @param jobInfo
* Job associated with new batches
* @param csvFileName
* The source file for batch data
*/
private List<BatchInfo> createBatchesFromCSVFile(BulkConnection connection,
JobInfo jobInfo, String csvFileName)
throws IOException, AsyncApiException {
List<BatchInfo> batchInfos = new ArrayList<BatchInfo>();
BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csvFileName))
);
// read the CSV header row
byte[] headerBytes = (rdr.readLine() + "\n").getBytes("UTF-8");
int headerBytesLength = headerBytes.length;
File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("bulkAPIInsert", ".csv");
// Split the CSV file into multiple batches
try {
FileOutputStream tmpOut = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
int maxBytesPerBatch = 10000000; // 10 million bytes per batch
int maxRowsPerBatch = 10000; // 10 thousand rows per batch
int currentBytes = 0;
int currentLines = 0;
String nextLine;
while ((nextLine = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
byte[] bytes = (nextLine + "\n").getBytes("UTF-8");
// Create a new batch when our batch size limit is reached
if (currentBytes + bytes.length > maxBytesPerBatch
|| currentLines > maxRowsPerBatch) {
createBatch(tmpOut, tmpFile, batchInfos, connection, jobInfo);
currentBytes = 0;
currentLines = 0;
}

if (currentBytes == 0) {
tmpOut = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
tmpOut.write(headerBytes);
currentBytes = headerBytesLength;
currentLines = 1;
}
tmpOut.write(bytes);
currentBytes += bytes.length;
currentLines++;
}
// Finished processing all rows
// Create a final batch for any remaining data
if (currentLines > 1) {
createBatch(tmpOut, tmpFile, batchInfos, connection, jobInfo);
}
} finally {
tmpFile.delete();
}
return batchInfos;
}
/**
* Create a batch by uploading the contents of the file.
* This closes the output stream.
*
* @param tmpOut
* The output stream used to write the CSV data for a single batch.
* @param tmpFile
* The file associated with the above stream.
* @param batchInfos
* The batch info for the newly created batch is added to this list.
* @param connection
* The BulkConnection used to create the new batch.
* @param jobInfo
* The JobInfo associated with the new batch.
*/
private void createBatch(FileOutputStream tmpOut, File tmpFile,
List<BatchInfo> batchInfos, BulkConnection connection, JobInfo jobInfo)
throws IOException, AsyncApiException {
tmpOut.flush();
tmpOut.close();
FileInputStream tmpInputStream = new FileInputStream(tmpFile);
try {
BatchInfo batchInfo =
connection.createBatchFromStream(jobInfo, tmpInputStream);
System.out.println(batchInfo);
batchInfos.add(batchInfo);
} finally {
tmpInputStream.close();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the code you used, so it is easier to help find a solution.

Comment: Hi Markus, i added the code

Answer (score 1):

The [Login](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) call against the Partner API returns a [LoginResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login_loginresult.htm#topic-title) response. This in turn includes a UserInfo of type [getUserInfoResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getuserinfo_getuserinforesult.htm?search_text=login). It is this inner type where `orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode` is defined.

The probably cause is that the internal representation of the WSDL that your local code has doesn't correspond to API v38.0 that you are calling. You are using the endpoint https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/**38.0**.

`orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode` was introduced in v14.0 (or earlier) of the Partner API, so the problem is likely in one of the adjacent elements in the response. I make that to be `orgAttachmentFileSizeLimit` or `orgDefaultCurrencyLocale`

I'm going to go with `orgDefaultCurrencyLocale` being the problem as it was introduced in v38.0 of the Partner WSDL. As such, try rolling your API version back to 37.0 or updating the `com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection` code to the latest WSDL.